# how to make a loop delay windows form c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to make an auto clicker that repeatedly clicks with a delayed interval between each click. I am using visual studio windows form app in c#.

Here is the code:

```
private void ClickButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool click = true;

     while (click == true) {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        ClickButton.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

The program seems to really hate the while loop. The program crashes every time I press the button.

Comment: What's the exception message when the program crashes? Stack overflow ?

Comment: You have created an endless loop. (No exit strategy) It is called recursive when you call a method from within the method.

Comment: You must either disable your button before launching the loop, create some outer `bool` variable and use another button upon clicking which this variable turns into `true`. You could check this variable in your loop: if it's true, then you just execute `break;`. You could, of course, use same button, but in this case you would need to adjust logic.

Comment: It is an endless loop.  And will eventually crash with this web site's name, takes a while.  The OS will step in and display the "Not Responding" ghost window first.  After a minute you might see the debugger MDA that warns about this.  You'll have to throw this away, use a Timer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timer to handle this problem. first add this namespace:

```
using System.Timers;
```

then add this methods and modify them:

```
    public void StartTimer()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
       //Call Click buttom
    }
```

Comment: I want to stress out that you could use Windows Forms specific timer: [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer). The advantages: 1) You can forget about thread safety. 2) A fresh Tick will never fire until the previous Tick has finished processing. 3) You can update user interface elements and controls directly from Tick event handling code, without calling Control.BeginInvoke or Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.